# Bootstrap 4 grid layout not working with dompdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, bootstrap-4, dompdf

I am using dompdf to render a PDF document. We use Bootstrap 4 on the whole application, so I would like to be able to use it in the twig template used to generate our document.

Currently, I'm facing a problem with Bootstrap 4 grid system not rendering well in the generated PDF: the element in a same .row div all pile up.

I'm sure the Bootstrap CSS is loaded in the template.

My code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            little text
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <h1>Big title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The generated PDF:
[image: screenshot of a pdf with all the text piled up]

**Update:** with `col-n` instead of `col-xs-n`

My code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            little text
        </div>
        <div class="col-11">
            <h1>Big title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot of a pdf with all the text piled up]

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, since [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#features) supports css 2.1, and bootstrap uses css3 for the layout (flexbox). You could try [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

Answer (score 0):

try this class `.col-1` and `.col-11`, or `.col-sm-1 .col-sm-11`

avaible:

```
.col-   .col-sm-    .col-md-    .col-lg-    .col-xl-
```

col-xs it's for bootstrap 3

Comment: thanks, I tried. It changed a little the output but did not fix my problem (I've edited my question to show the results)

Comment: @LucileDT i found this $options = new \Dompdf\Options();
$options->setDpi(150);
$dompdf = new \Dompdf($options);

Comment: I tried to change the DPI of the file with no results

Comment: looks like this is a unresolved cold case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

[image: using col-]

Than I found this issues related at: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/653

One tip tha I tried was changing the class col- to col-xs- than the layout is better now. Not perfect as in browser but better than before.

I'm using bootstrap v4.4.1.

Pdf after change: [image: after change col- to col-xs-]

Comment: I'm using <div class="container">

Comment: can you share me the code, I have same kind of issue, somehow "row" can't apply in PDF